How to write a BigQuery query to find rows where a value has changed but also return the previous row before that change
I am new to BQ and need to write a query that returns rows where a particular value has changed on or after 01/09/2024 and then also return the last row before that change (unless the particular value is the same as the previous most recent change). Also, I don't want to return a row if a particular second field value has changed.
Please see screenshot of the data in bigquery with some commentary added and the result I'm looking to return.
Sample data and expected result
Appreciate any assistance in how this can be achieved.
EDIT:
Example dataset where UserId '987654' has no value changes across all rows - the date isn't copnsidered a changed value.
WITH
  myTable AS ( (
    SELECT 123456 AS UserId, DATE('2024-09-01') AS EffectiveDate, 'Supervisor' AS Role, 2000 AS PostCode, 'Suburb1' AS Suburb, 'State1' AS State, 'Country1' AS Country UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-03'), 'Supervisor', 2001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-05'), 'Supervisor', 2001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-07'), 'Supervisor', 2001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-09'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-11'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-13'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-15'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-17'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-09'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-11'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-13'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-15'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-17'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-19'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-21'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-23'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-25'), 'Leader', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1')
  ORDER BY
    UserId,
    EffectiveDate )
SELECT
  UserId,
  EffectiveDate,
  Role,
  PostCode,
  Suburb,
  State,
  Country,
FROM
  myTable
QUALIFY
  (PostCode != LAG(Postcode) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EffectiveDate)
    OR LAG(Postcode) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EffectiveDate) IS NULL)
  AND (NOT Role != LAG(Role) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EffectiveDate)
    OR LAG(Role) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EffectiveDate) IS NULL)

Result returns a single row for UserId '987654' even no there weren't any changes across any of the rows for that user - the date isn't considered a changed value. Can users that have no changes across any rows not show in the result?
UserId  EffectiveDate   Role        PostCode    Suburb  State   Country
123456  2024-09-01      Supervisor  2000        Suburb1 State1  Country1
123456  2024-09-03      Supervisor  2001        Suburb1 State1  Country1
123456  2024-09-09      Supervisor  2002        Suburb2 State2  Country1
987654  2024-09-09      Leader      3000        Suburb1 State1  Country1


Why is this tagged with MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Apologies, it should have been sql and BQ only - other tags removed.

Please clarify: you wrote that all rows in which one value has changed (compared to the previous row, I assume) shall be returned "and then also return the last row before that change". The latter is, however, not reproduced in your example data.

That's correct. It should compare based on previous row. What I meant for the second part was return the previous row where the initial value had changed but I think that change would be picked up earlier when comparing the rows.

The following query first creates your example table (please prepare this by yourself in future questions, it would be convenient for people willing to help you), and then uses the LAG Window Function to get your expected result.
WITH
  myTable AS ( (
    SELECT 123456 AS UserId, DATE('2024-09-01') AS EffectiveDate, 'Supervisor' AS Role, 2000 AS PostCode, 'Suburb1' AS Suburb, 'State1' AS State, 'Country1' AS Country UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-03'), 'Supervisor', 2001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-05'), 'Supervisor', 2001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-07'), 'Supervisor', 2001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-09'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-11'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-13'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-15'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, DATE('2024-09-17'), 'Supervisor', 2002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-09'), 'Supervisor', 3000, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-11'), 'Supervisor', 3001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-13'), 'Supervisor', 3001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-15'), 'Supervisor', 3001, 'Suburb1', 'State1', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-17'), 'Supervisor', 3002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-19'), 'Supervisor', 3002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-21'), 'Supervisor', 3002, 'Suburb2', 'State2', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-23'), 'Leader', 3003, 'Suburb3', 'State3', 'Country1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, DATE('2024-09-25'), 'Supervisor', 3003, 'Suburb3', 'State3', 'Country1')
  ORDER BY
    UserId,
    EffectiveDate )
SELECT
  UserId,
  EffectiveDate,
  Role,
  PostCode,
  Suburb,
  State,
  Country,
FROM
  myTable
QUALIFY
  (PostCode != LAG(Postcode) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EffectiveDate)
    OR LAG(Postcode) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EffectiveDate) IS NULL)
  AND (NOT Role != LAG(Role) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EffectiveDate)
    OR LAG(Role) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EffectiveDate) IS NULL)

QUALIFY filters the result, after the analytic functions are evaluated. The criteria after the OR is needed to catch the first row, where LAG(Postcode) resp. LAG(Role) evaluate to NULL.
The result of this query is the following:
UserId  EffectiveDate   Role        PostCode    Suburb  State   Country
123456  2024-09-01      Supervisor  2000        Suburb1 State1  Country1
123456  2024-09-03      Supervisor  2001        Suburb1 State1  Country1
123456  2024-09-09      Supervisor  2002        Suburb2 State2  Country1
987654  2024-09-09      Supervisor  3000        Suburb1 State1  Country1
987654  2024-09-11      Supervisor  3001        Suburb1 State1  Country1
987654  2024-09-17      Supervisor  3002        Suburb2 State2  Country1


Thank you @TillK. I wasn't aware of those functions, and I will be sure to create a sample table of data.
I have a follow up question - if none of the QUALIFY criteria is met, than it still returns a row for that UserId. How can this be excluded from the result? For instance, if UserId '987654' has no value changes, it should not return a row.

@JohnnyS4322 I'm not sure if I understand your question. The QUALIFY clause, as it is, filters out rows where no values have changed. For example, the rows of the dates 2024-09-15 and 2024-09-21 for UserId '987654' are not included in the result.

There are instances where a UserId has no changes across any rows and it still returns a single line. If I  were to use UserId '987654' as an example, let's say there were no value changes across all 9 rows in the sample data provided, the query still returns a single row for that UserId. I'll see if I can edit the original post tp show this scenario.

Wondering @TillK if a count of results per UserId can be done and then exclude those UserId’s that only have one record? Or cannot be done with the QUALIFY clause?

Ah, now I see. In that case, you can simply remove the ORs in the QUALIFY clause, which were added only to include the first row for each UserId.
